# Java source code management with different IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Is it necessary to use the same ide to program in java? For example, I use IntelliJ to build a small java project about 2000 lines. Then the marker uses Eclipse IDE to mark this project. Does he need to import all the source code into a new project and set up everything for it?  I didn't use any add-on on this IDE.

The reason I asked this question because I receive huge grade duction for using different IDE, the prof response me and said marker need rebuild everything for using different ide.

I drag my source code into Eclipse, and it works very well, so I am confused am I right or wrong?

Comment: Honestly - and this is my opinion (which may not make this a good question) - it's really not your problem if they don't know how to import source code into their IDE.  You have the power and freedom to use whatever tooling you feel most comfortable with; since they don't provide you with Maven or Gradle to simplify pulling dependencies in, it's the responsibility of the teacher/grader to accept this as a shortcoming, and to import your code.  Professionally I work in a shop with people using IntelliJ (myself included), Eclipse, Vim, and Sublime Text.  It *literally* doesn't matter.

Comment: Java code is Java code. If the IDE matters, then something is wrong. Professional  projects use a build tool (Gradle, Maven) to build a project. Not an IDE. The IDEs can import the build tool configuration files to set up an IDE project.

Comment: @JBNizet That of course assumes that OP did provide a build script, and wasn't just relying on the IDE to do the build.

Comment: Usually all IDE-specific files in a project are supposed to be ignored by svn/git. If the IDE of some other person matters, that person is not doing it right.

Comment: @Andreas It would be great for a student to do that. But my point is rather that a teacher, who is supposed to be more competent than his/her students, shouldn't impose an IDE and should be able to deal with Java code, even without a build file.

Comment: @JBNizet Wow, *competent* teacher?!? You're reaching, given some of the stories we hear on here.

Comment: it's usually the teacher's way or the highway. You either adapt and get familiar with their IDE of choice or pay the consequences (get lower scores on homework) during your time enrolled in the class. If nothing else it forces you to learn another IDE and in the grand scheme of things there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: To the OP: most good IDEs use a build script, and so will build in any IDE or on the command line.  However most IDEs also require that a project with existing sources be "set up"  in some way.  The build script and the source files are two separate things, and complicated projects can have complicated file structures.  So any IDE has to be flexible (and allow the user to specify the source file set) if it's going to be useful.

Comment: I'll agree with Makoto though.  As long as you supply a build script and a sane project file set, then it's up to the user of an IDE to understand how to import a project into their favorite IDE.  You can't be responsible for testing every possible development environment.

Comment: Thanks all, I was so down to receive a lower grade on a project, even though the program runs well. I get duction on IDE, naming, indentation(even though I used python style and auto format in idea j). I was complaining the master student CANT even write a script or drag source code into IDE to mark my assignment. I agree with RAZ_Muh_Taz and believe Makoto theory. I used Maven to manage files as JB Nizet said, I guess I shouldn't give a **** for the grade.

Comment: Look.  It is technically possible (and not hard) for someone to load a program developed in one IDE into a different one.  However, the real lesson here is for you.  You need to read and understand the requirements.  And meet them.  If that includes strange / unnecessary / inconvenient things ... then so be it!  In the real world, if the customer specifically asks for paper copies of your javadocs, you give him paper copies ... or risk not getting paid for your work.   Same principle applies here.

Comment: @StephenC right...who paid money who is boss